# Magento 2 how to setting Billing Address qty

Tags: magento2.3, customer-address, billing

i'm using magento 2.3.x , how can i setting Billing Address qty to 1 only? it just can give custumer to add one address or 2, thank you!

i want customer only can setting one or two upper limit billing and shipping address, can not setting three or more address, included account dashboard address and checkout page.

Comment: Specify your requirement in details.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i want customer only can setting one or two upper limit billing and shipping address, can not setting three or more address, included account dashboard address and checkout page.

Comment: ok then you need to create custom extension and create observer or plugin to do this one.